# List index out of bounds :0

Tags: apex, trigger

I am getting an error of

> List index out of bounds :0

Please guide me on how to fix it as I have checked the list as null in the code but I am still getting the error.

```
trigger PAM_AssignOwnerfromOrganization on Process_Adherence_Monitoring__c (before insert) {

    Set<id> accountId = new Set<id>();
    system.debug('accountId-->'+accountId);

    List<Contact> conList = new List<Contact>();

    For(Process_Adherence_Monitoring__c pam : Trigger.new)
    {
      if(pam.Organization_Name__c!= Null)
      accountId.add(pam.Organization_Name__c);   
    }

    conList = [select id,Name,Community_Profile__c,Inactive_Contact__c FROM Contact WHERE AccountId IN :accountId AND Community_Profile__c INCLUDES  ('PAM') AND Inactive_Contact__c = False];
    List<User> userlist = new List<User>();

    userlist = [Select Id FROM User Where ContactId != Null AND ContactId =: conList[0].id];


    system.debug('conList-->'+conList);
    system.debug('userlist-->'+userlist);

      for(Process_Adherence_Monitoring__c pam : Trigger.new)
      {
        if(!userlist.isEmpty()){
          pam.OwnerId = userlist[0].Id; 
        }
        else
        {
            pam.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId(); 
        }  
      }  
}
```

Comment: Error on which line?

Comment: You have a problem here - ContactId =: conList[0].id

Comment: Error Line - no 17! @d_k

Comment: What is the issue? @RahulSharma

Comment: Your query of contact isn't getting any record

Comment: how are you matching OwnerId in last loop?

Comment: @RahulSharma I want to assign the logged in user if there is no record in the list and a user which is retrieved from the list has to be assigned if there is a record!

Comment: So, I suppose Organization_Name__c is your matching key

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether the list has any value before using a value in a particular index of the list

```
if(conList.size()>0)
{
userlist = [Select Id FROM User Where ContactId != Null AND ContactId  = :conList[0].id];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to just just this 2 Lines of code.

```
if(conList.size() > 0 && conList != null) {
     userlist = [Select Id FROM User Where ContactId != Null AND ContactId =:         conList[0].id];
}
```

Further when you will going to access any List or Map please check with ".size() > 0 && != null". It'll never throw this type of error.